# gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, dns, hostname

I want to resolve the ip address of hostnames from a text file. Below code works fine for ipv4 address:

```
hostname1.txt:
google.com
yahoo.com
facebook.com
cnn.com
```

```
with open('hostname1.txt','r') as hostnames:
    for website in hostnames:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(website.strip())
        
        print ('{0} ip address is: {1}'.format(website,ip))
```

For ipv6, I used the below code and it works fine when there is only one hostname in the text file. if there are multiple hostnames in the text file, I get this error "gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

```
import socket

with open('hostname1.txt') as f:
    hostname = f.readlines()
    
    for website in hostname:
        ais = socket.getaddrinfo(website,0,0,0,0)
        
        for result in ais:
            ip = result[-1][0]
            print ('{0} ip address is {1}'.format(website,ip))
```

```
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: Try and debug your code and see what happens on the second run of the loop. If it works the first time and not the second time then something is definitely going wrong.

Comment: Please edit the title so that it is clear

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` keeps newline char, so your `hostname` list is `['google.com\n', 'yahoo.com\n', 'facebook.com\n', 'cnn.com\n']`
You stripped `\nl` in IPV4 part not in IPV6 part.
Use the following:

```
ais = socket.getaddrinfo(website.rstrip(),0,0,0,0)
```

and you will get correct result.